# Powershell- how to get a one-line command to find a string and replace it by adding 2 new lines

Tags: powershell

Is it possible in Powershell to get a single line command to find a string and replace it by adding 2 new lines with a different value leaving the beginning and end of the file unchanged?

`(Get-Content -Path C:\test.txt) -replace 'aaa=0','aaa=20 \n\r g=11111 \n\r g=2222' | Set-Content -Path C:\test.txt)`

source file:

test=txt

dds=1aa

ab=test

aaa=0

bbb=4444

target file:

test=txt

dds=1aa

**aaa=20

g=11111

g=2222**

bbb=4444

Comment: `(Get-Content -Path C:\tests\test.txt) | ForEach-Object{ $_; if ($_ -match "aaa=0") {"g=11111";"g=22222" }} | Set-Content -Path C:\tests\test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert CRLF without adding literal newlines in the source code, use the `` `r `` and `` `n `` escape sequences in an expandable string:

```
... -replace 'aaa=0',"aaa=20 `r`ng=11111 `r`ng=2222"
```